# Recursively convert (label, list) pairs to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, zip, iteration

I have a data-structure currently in the format of nested strings and lists corresponding to said strings, for example:

```
'Document types'
['Surveys and overviews', 'Reference works', 'General conference proceedings', 'Biographies', 'General literature', 'Computing standards, RFCs and guidelines']
'Cross-computing tools and techniques
['Reliability', 'Empirical studies', 'Measurement', 'Metrics', 'Evaluation', 'Experimentation', 'Estimation', 'Design', 'Performance', 'Validation', 'Verification']
```

where each list may be a list of strings (i.e. the base case and deepest level), or another series of label-list pairs.

I've developed code to convert the top-most layer, but cannot find a way to have it iteratively or recursively perform the action on the layer below.

My code so far:

```
  def recursive(self, data):
    for label, tags in zip(*[iter(data)]*2):
      self.newData[label] = tags

    return self.newData
```

Example input structure:
[image]

Comment: is your data structure a json? curious as to how you mark levels?

Comment: It's a screen-shot of the Pycharm visual view of the dictionary :-)